# UTF-8 character set

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, utf-8, ascii

I have a form field which would allow up to 120 characters and also accept all UTF-8 unicode character set including special, numeric and Alpha to provide for i18ncharacters. It should ignore leading and trailing spaces

As I have mostly used limited ASCII set, I am not sure what UTF-8 would include.

Could you please guide me about the basic differences of the ASCII/UTF-8 and the complete character set which should be allowed given the above requirement.

Thank you.

Comment: did you ever read this? http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, UTF-8 is a superset of US-ASCII.  Any character in ASCII can be represented in UTF-8, and using the same bit representations.  UTF-8 is one representation of Unicode, that allows for representation of any currently defined character.

Answer (score 1):

ASCII contains only 128 characters and the latest version of Unicode contains more than 109,000 characters covering 93 scripts.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII - the full description about ASCII

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode - the wiki article about Unicode

http://unicode.org/charts/ - list of Unicode charts

Comment: Thx a lot...Since the charset is so vast, Is there any standard way of writing a regex for what i need in utf-8?